# I need to add a "login" screen before my main window in a wpf program

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

So i already made my program but my client asked for a mock login screen before the application starts, it is not a real login more like a "please input key to continue" screen. any ideas on how to make that screen launch before my main window and only after authentication deploy my app?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. What have you tried?

Comment: right now im messing around with app.xaml to try and set up startup configurations

Comment: Ok, make some effort to solve this yourself first and come back when you have some code and specific problem. Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to learn how to use the site and how to ask a question.

Comment: already figured it out, thanks anyway guys

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to open the App.xaml file of yout project and change the StartupURI component to the window of your choice